# Understanding concurrentModificationException and implementation of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I tried to reproduce ConcurrentModificationException myself by writing the following code:

```
List<String> last = new ArrayList<>();
last.add("a");
last.add("b");
for(String i : last){
    System.out.println(i);
    last.remove(i);
}
System.out.println(last);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/rIO27k)

Since, the [documentation of `ArrayList` mentioned](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed
>   as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees
>   in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification.

I expected that in single-threaded programs such detection is straghtforward. But the program printed

```
a
[b]
```

instead. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through a list, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-list-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-removing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the documentation:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are **fail-fast**: **if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created**, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, **the iterator will throw a**
>   **ConcurrentModificationException**

Because you are looping through the list using the new syntax `for(String i : last)` an iterator is created for you and **you can't modify the list while looping it**.

This exception **is not related to multithreading**. Also working with only one thread you can throw that exception.

Internally there is a variable `modCount` that is incremented for every modification to the structure of the list. When the iterator is first created it saves that value of `modCount` in a variable `expectedModCount`. Every subsequent modification check if that value of `expectedModCount` is equal to `modCount`. If not a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown.

I add the code of remove as an example. The same for `add`, `addAll` and all others methods that modify the list.

```
public E remove(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    // Check if a modification should thrown a ConcurrentModificationException
    checkForComodification();  

    E result = parent.remove(parentOffset + index);
    this.modCount = parent.modCount;
    this.size--;
    return result;
}

final void checkForComodification() {
    if (expectedModCount != ArrayList.this.modCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: You State "an iterator is created for you and you can't modify the list while looping it.", but that is exactly what St.Antario does. They are able to remove an element from the list while looping. They expected an exception to be thrown but it wasn't thrown. They'd like to know why.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is equivalent to the following:

```
   List<String> last = new ArrayList<>();
   last.add("a");
   last.add("b");
   for(Iterator<String> i = last.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
       String value = i.next();
       System.out.println(value);
       last.remove(value);
   }
   System.out.println(last);
```

The flow of the `for` loop is:

```
 System.out.println(value); // prints "a"
 last.remove(value);        // removes "a" from the list
 i.hasNext()                // exits the loop, since i.hasNext() is false
 System.out.println(last);  // prints "[b]" - the updated list
```

That's why you get your output and no `ConcurrentModificationException`.
You will get `ConcurrentModificationException` if you'll add another value to your list (e.g. `last.add("c")`), because then `i.hasNext()` will be true after the first iteration and `i.next()` will throw the exception.

Comment: Yes, the crux of the matter is that i.hasNext() is false so the check for the co-modification never happens and the exception is never thrown. The reason it is false is because as far as the iterator is concerned, it has stepped once through a list of size one and so it is done

Answer (score 3):

**Itr** class in **ArrayList** class has following methods

```
public boolean hasNext() {
            return cursor != size;
        }

 final void checkForComodification() {
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
```

Here, **modCount** is the number of times list has been structurally modified. When we create for loop, internally an iterator will be created and **expectedModCount** will be initialized to **modCount**.

When there are only 2 elements in the list and after removing one element, **for loop** will check the condition using **hasNext()** method call. So, condition **cursor != size** (1!=1) will be met first. Hence, loop won't proceed further and ConcurrentModificationException will not be thrown.

But, when there are 1,3,4 etc number of elements are there in the list then, **for loop** will proceed further after **hasNext()** method call. But, while fetching the element using **next()** method inside **for loop**, it will call **checkForComodification()** and condition **modCount != expectedModCount** will be met. Hence, exception will be thrown.

Comment: This is clear and detail explanation of the `flow`. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Leonli :)

Answer (score 1):

For two values, it will not fail because the for loop will be exited.  Add a third element and you will get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

```
List<String> last = new ArrayList<>();
last.add("a");
last.add("b");
last.add("c");
for(String i : last){
    System.out.println(i);
    last.remove(i);
}
System.out.println(last);
```